# Website doesn't display in firefox but is fine in all other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-9

For some reason my web page is not display correctly in Firefox. It is displayed correctly in IE9, Safari, chrome.

In Firefox if I zoom out or in the layout changes. But then the YouTube video begins to smear and pixelate. I asked a friend to check Firefox on their computer and the same thing happens.

http://wwww.streetstyles4all.co.uk/images/screen_shot.jpg

The screen shot from top left shows how the page loads.  Top right shows after I zoom in or out, and bottom left is after I scroll up and down.

HTML:

The HTML for the section in question is:

```
 <div id="homewallcontainer">

                <div id="homesidenavcontainer">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/23/850302323.js"></script>
                </div>

                <div id="newsletterblurb">
                <p>
                Learn everything you need to get yourself going in the world of street dance, tips, facts, what to wear, music, videos and more.  Just fill in the form above - simple!
                </p>
                </div>  

                <div id="contentcontainerhome2">
                   <h1>Street Styles 4 All is the place to be for street dance! With classes, DVD's that are sold worlwide, dancers for hire, streetwear...find out why you should choose Street Styles 4 All:
                   </h1>
                            <div id="homess4atrailer">
        <iframe width="466" height="302" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QyhgZ6I_DHo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>


           </div>


    </div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#homewallcontainer {
background: url("images/wall.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 542px;
margin-top: -1px;
width: 960px;
}

#homesidenavcontainer {
float: left;
margin-left: 41px;
margin-top: 110px;
width: 253px;
}

#homesidenavcontainer {
float: left;
margin-left: 41px;
margin-top: 110px;
width: 253px;
}

#contentcontainerhome2 {
float: right;
margin-right: 17px;
margin-top: 46px;
width: 528px;
}

#homess4atrailer {
margin-left: 56px;
padding: 38px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you, maybe, put the code that is not working in your question, for more detailed information? And what version of Firefox are you using? Maybe you need to make a good revision of your code and make sure your code suits the browsers you are using. Sometimes, what works in one browser does not work in another. CSS3 between Firefox and IE is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

I spot 2 mistakes in your html snippet. An extra `</div>` at the end, with a strange ' and the `allowfullscreen` in the iframe that is invalid. Have you tried [validating](http://validator.w3.org/) your code already?